# Поиск сигнатуры в процессе

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно найти по какому адресу в процессе расположен необходимый паттерн. Как реализовать такой поиск сигнатуры?

Comment: В каком виде представлена у вас сигнатура?

Comment: В виде HEX последовательности.

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам подойдут обычные регулярки. Они работают с байтами.

Comment: Михаил, а как с помощью регулярки получить адрес моей сигнатуры в запущенном процессе? Мне нужно это для того, чтобы по смещению от сигнатуры получить необходимые данные

Comment: Там есть метод, возвращающий индекс начала совпадения паттерна. Берёте адрес начала памяти Вашей программы, добавляете к нему этот индекс, находите нужный адрес.

Comment: "Там" - это где?

Comment: В объекте `_sre.SRE_Match`, который возвращает функция `re.search`. Метод `start` этого объекта вернёт Вам индекс начала вхождения паттерна в строку (байты).

Comment: Не в процессе, а в экзешнике, но суть та же: https://twitter.com/insolor/status/974705751603269634

Comment: Artmoney вернулся?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо Михаилу Муругову за помощь. Давно уже реализовал, вспомнил про свой вопрос и решил поделиться кодом.

```py
import pymem
import pymem.process
import re

pm = pymem.Pymem('process_name.exe')
# может быть длл-модуль или сам .exe
process_module = pymem.process.module_from_name(pm.process_handle, 'process_module.dll')
# берём байтики из нашего модуля
module_data = pm.read_bytes(process_module.lpBaseOfDll, process_module.SizeOfImage)
# ищем паттерн и получаем его адрес, прибавляя адрес паттерна к адресу, по которому расположено начало модуля
address = process_module.lpBaseOfDll + re.search(rb'\x90\x90\x90\x90', module_data).start()
```